# Crystal Lang Compiler Speed

Tags: crystal-lang

I was just wondering about the compiler speed of the Crystal programming language. It feels relatively slow:

```
➜ ~/Code/crystal/crystal_scheduler (master ✘)✹✭ ᐅ time crystal build --release src/crystal_scheduler.cr
34.64s user 1.10s system 93% cpu 38.174 total
➜ ~/Code/crystal/crystal_scheduler (master ✘)✹✭ ᐅ time crystal build --release src/crystal_scheduler.cr
36.11s user 0.83s system 93% cpu 39.465 total
➜ ~/Code/crystal/crystal_scheduler (master ✘)✹✭ ᐅ time crystal build src/crystal_scheduler.cr
8.09s user 0.89s system 181% cpu 4.956 total
```

The code is relatively small, two shards, two classes. Compared to other compilation times I know from Java, this feels like long times.

I get that release compiling is slow, but the git book states:

> The reason for this is that performance without full optimizations is
>   still pretty good and provides fast compile times, so you can use the
>   crystal command almost as if it were an interpreter.

But 8s feels a bit slow to claim that you can use it "almost as if it were an interpreter".

I was just wondering if
 - a) my compilation is especially slow / the compile times are normal
 - b) how it compares to other languages in your experience

Compilation Stats:

```
Parse:                             00:00:00.0007470 (   0.25MB)
Semantic (top level):              00:00:00.3968920 (  36.08MB)
Semantic (new):                    00:00:00.0019210 (  44.08MB)
Semantic (type declarations):      00:00:00.0355760 (  44.08MB)
Semantic (abstract def check):     00:00:00.0012690 (  44.08MB)
Semantic (ivars initializers):     00:00:00.0094640 (  44.08MB)
Semantic (cvars initializers):     00:00:00.0394420 (  44.08MB)
Semantic (main):                   00:00:00.6025030 ( 108.14MB)
Semantic (cleanup):                00:00:00.0012750 ( 108.14MB)
Semantic (recursive struct check): 00:00:00.0018930 ( 108.14MB)
Codegen (crystal):                 00:00:00.7354530 ( 140.27MB)
Codegen (bc+obj):                  00:00:33.2533520 ( 140.27MB)
Codegen (linking):                 00:00:00.3647440 ( 140.27MB)
```

My System:

```
➜ crystal -v
Crystal 0.22.0 (2017-04-20) LLVM 4.0.0
```

Hardware Overview:

```
 Model Name:    MacBook Pro
 Model Identifier:  MacBookPro11,1
 Processor Name:    Intel Core i5
 Processor Speed:   2,8 GHz
 Number of Processors:  1
 Total Number of Cores: 2
 L2 Cache (per Core):   256 KB
 L3 Cache:  3 MB
 Memory:    16 GB
```

Comment: That sounds a bit slow to me, you can use the `--stats` argument to the crystal compiler to estimate where the slowness comes from. It's really hard to debug "slow" without any details or code so not much I can do, other to say that it does seem strange that it's so slow.

Comment: I added `--stats` output. I am using kemal.cr, but its basically only one route, no classes, no nothing.

Comment: That LLVM codegen phase looks way too long compared to the rest of the passes. Is that a release build? For example, this is stats output of me building the whole compiler (which is a lot more code), take note of the amount of time spent in each part relative to each other: https://aww.moe/5n3ql4.txt

Comment: Interesting... Yes, it was a release build

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `crystal build --no-debug my_code.cr` to improve compiler speed a bit.

See: [Why Crystal use too much memory?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/crystal-lang/xbb7RG6W0tM) and [Crystal for large scale programs](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/crystal-lang/xG5MQXTOyj8)

Also, I suggest you to add `--progress` flag.

Progress flag adds more information about compilation process, showing stats for every file generated on codegen phase.

```
>>> crystal build -s --no-debug -p my_code.cr
Parse:                             00:00:00.0008560 (   0.34MB)
Semantic (top level):              00:00:00.2588280 (  27.91MB)
Semantic (new):                    00:00:00.0018450 (  35.91MB)
Semantic (type declarations):      00:00:00.0263890 (  35.91MB)
Semantic (abstract def check):     00:00:00.0015270 (  35.91MB)
Semantic (ivars initializers):     00:00:00.0018980 (  35.91MB)
Semantic (cvars initializers):     00:00:00.0158470 (  35.91MB)
Semantic (main):                   00:00:00.4168150 (  60.10MB)
Semantic (cleanup):                00:00:00.0010650 (  60.10MB)
Semantic (recursive struct check): 00:00:00.0008110 (  60.10MB)
Codegen (crystal):                 00:00:00.3381910 (  68.10MB)
[12/13] [67/215] Codegen (bc+obj)
        ~~~~~~~~
          (1)
```

(1) Amount of files processed, you can see these files on Crystal cache directory.

BTW, I compiled a whole Amber project in less than 30 seconds with 10 shards on an old Intel Celeron PC. Don't use `--release` flag on development phase, but on production. (LLVM take a lot of time doing optimizations)

```
>>> cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name"
model name      : Intel(R) Celeron(R) 2957U @ 1.40GHz
>>> shards list
Shards installed:
  * amber (0.1.3)
  * radix (0.3.8)
  * kilt (0.1.0)
  * slang (1.6.1)
  * redis (1.8.0)
  * quartz-mailer (0.1.0)
  * kilt (0.1.0)
  * smtp (0.1.0)
  * granite_orm (0.6.2)
  * kemalyst-validators (0.2.0)
  * db (0.4.2)
  * sqlite3 (0.8.2)
  * db (0.4.2)
>>> time crystal build -p src/app.cr -o app --no-debug
real    0m24.320s
user    0m26.700s
sys     0m1.437s
>>> time crystal build -p src/app.cr -o app --no-debug          
real    0m6.225s
user    0m5.727s
sys     0m0.970s
```

Comment: Also see: [Why the compiler is slow and consumes a lot of memory](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/4864)